# Web-Scraping, get a csv file from url address

Tags: python-3.x, url, request, export-to-csv

I have a stupid issue. I have an address that generates a csv file immediately when I copy that to the browser. But I need to do it with python code, so I tried to do something like that:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WSE/TSGAMES.csv?column_index=4&start_date=2018-01-01&end_date=2018-12-31&collapse=monthly&transform=rdiff&api_key=AZ964MpikzEYAyLGfJD2Y
csv = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() 
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as fx: # bytes, hence mode 'wb'
    fx.write(csv)
```

But I got an error: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Bad Request

Do you know the reason and could you help ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* I should state that your link did not work for me, and my quandl API is different then yours.

This is pretty easy to do with the requests module:

```
import requests


filename = 'test_file.csv'
link = 'your link here'
data = requests.get(link)  # request the link, response 200 = success


with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.content)  # write content of request to file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

That link doesn't work for me.  Try it like this (generic example).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import StringIO
import csv
data = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/files/MontyPythonAlbums.csv").read().decode('ascii', 'ignore')
dataFile = StringIO(data)
csvReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
with open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/example.csv', 'w') as myFile:  
   writer = csv.writer(myFile)
   writer.writerows(csvReader)
```